# Teste de verificação retorna campo vazio, porém não quero que printe sem o alert em branco no nome

Tags: javascript

alert("Bem vindo ao consultório digital")
function menssage(message) {
let peoples = []

```
while (message != 3) {
    let pos = ""
    for (let index = 0; index < peoples.length; index++) {
        const element = peoples[index]
        pos += ("O paciente " + element + " Se encontra na posição " + `${index + 1}º da fila\n`)

    }

    message = prompt(`1-Cadastrar novo paciente\n2-Consultar Paciente\n3-Fechar o consultório\n\nPessoas na fila:\n` + pos)

    if (message == 1) {
       let name = peoples.push(prompt("Insira o nome da pessoa a ser cadastrada na fila"))
        if(peoples == ""){
            alert("Não deixe o campo vazio")
            menssage()

        }else if(name === null){
            menssage()
        }

    }

    //Aqui a condição verifica se há pacientes ou não na fila 

    else if (message == 2 && peoples == "") {
        alert("Não há mais pacientes para serem consultados")
    }

    else if (message == 2 && peoples !== "") {
        let consultado = peoples.shift()
        alert("Consultando o paciente " + consultado)


    }  

    else if (message !== 4 && message >= 4) {
        alert("Escolha uma opção válida")
    }

}
```

}

menssage()

Comment: Eu ainda não sei mexer bem no stack, porém explicando o código, ele adiciona pessoas em uma fila, mas infelizmente está adicionando pessoas " vazias " na fila, dentro do array. quero que a verificação impeça isso, mas não estou conseguindo...

Comment: Nesse trecho `if(peoples == ""){ alert("Não deixe o campo vazio")`  poderia por mais uma condição  como  `if(name === "" || name === null){alert("Não deixe o campo vazio")} else {          peoples.push(name)}`

Comment: Se o campo estiver **vazio** ou ser **null** emitira um `alert`.. caso contrario `else` se encarrega de adicionar.

Comment: No caso eu percebi que só emite o alert quando não tem nada no array, a partir do momento que eu coloco um nome, e depois tento por no prompt um valor vazio, ele coloca esse valor no array porque no if a variável name não é mais vazio. Justamente esse problema que quero resolver mas não consigo... :(

Comment: Estava verificando `peoples`e não se o campo estava vazio, e nesse trecho do código `if(peoples == ""){ alert("Não deixe o campo vazio") menssage()` chamando a função **menssage()** estava causando um **loop** infinito!

Comment: sim, apaguei a chamada da função, mas infelizmente ainda salva o valor vazio no array...

Comment: certo, então sua questão principal é o `prompt` , pode fazer uma verificação no **prompt** com **do-while** ou  **if** se é por ele o **Cadastrar novo paciente** pode usar um dos dois. antes do `prompt` verifique

Comment: acho que seria isso.  `if (message == 1) { let name = prompt("Insira o nome da pessoa a ser cadastrada na fila"); if(!name){ alert("Não deixe o campo vazio");  menssage()  }peoples.push(name); }`creio eu pelo que mencionou.

Comment: dessa forma armazena  **nome** nesse variavel "name" e verifica se essa variável é vazia. e acaba com o loop infinito.

Comment: Deu certo, porém se não por um nome na string, ela estando vazia, retorna a função do menu totalmente limpa sem a lista do array, aparentemente "apagando" os valores, no caso eu queria que ele apenas pedisse o prompt novamente, sem apagar os valores.

Comment: teria que por em loop infinito, abaixo da verificação  **(message == 1) {**  implemente o  `while(true){}` assim nao apagara mas sempre pedira outro nome

Comment: como sugestão vocÊs deveriam mover essa conversa para o chat, é melhor para discutir lá :) https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if(name == ""){
                    alert("Você precisa por um nome válido")
                 peoples.pop()
                }
```

`resolvi o problema dessa forma, apenas colocando uma condição para tirar do array um valor vazio que acaba de entrar no array`

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).